# How to create Create for ManyToMany relation with through?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have models like:

```
class Playlist(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, unique=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    videos = models.ManyToManyField(Video, through='PlaylistVideo')

class PlaylistVideo(models.Model):
    playlist = models.ForeignKey(Playlist)
    video =    models.ForeignKey(Video)
    position = models.IntegerField()

class Video(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    thumb =  models.URLField(blank=True)
    duration = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I want to write POST (create) for Playlist an API. Not sure how to handle videos field.

1. How to send values for videos field?

Django 1.8 and django-rest-framework

Thanks

Comment: What are you using for your API?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [DRF documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#manytomanyfields-with-a-through-model) :

> By default, relational fields that target a ManyToManyField with a through model specified are set to read-only.

So you most definitely CAN NOT create `Video` instances when creating a `Playlist`.

Now, considering you already have `Video` objects, and you want to create a `Playlist` which contains some of those videos, there are two ways to go about this.

1. You create your m2m relations at the same time as you create the `Playlist` :

   ```
   class PlaylistSerializer(ModelSerializer):

       videos = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True)

       class Meta:
           model = Playlist
   ```
2. You only create the `Playlist` on `POST`, without any videos, and then you create another endpoint (e.g. `playlist/<playlist_id>/videos/`) where you add/remove the videos that you want.

Both have pros and cons, but my opinion is that you should first design you API, thinking also about how you will continue editing that `Playlist`.

Do you add videos one by one ? Do you add them in bulk ?
How do you remove a video ? Can that be done in bulk ?

Once you've got the right answer to those questions, implementation should be fairly simple.

Good luck!